# Using Powershell to set user permissions in Reporting Services

Tags: powershell, ssrs-2008

Apologies if this appears to be a gimme-teh-codez question, but i'm asking this because i'm a n00b when it comes to Powershell.

How do i use Powershell to add a particular domain user or group to a specific reporting role in SSRS2008 (say the Content Manager or Browser role)? Is there a simple one or two line script to achieve it?

Thanks!

(I have previously posted this question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066869/using-powershell-to-set-user-permissions-in-reporting-services)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across this question whilst trying to find the same myself.
In the end, I wrote this function, which works with SSRS 2008 (as originally requested), all the way up to the current version of SSRS (2016).

Whist it's not a two-line answer, it does define a function that, once created, provides a single-line method... so in my mind, that counts (especially as you can't do this with just two lines).

Hope someone finds it useful!

```
function Add-SSRSUserRole
(   
    [string]$reportServerUrl,[string]$userGroup,[string]$requiredRole,[string]$folder,[bool]$inheritFromParent
)
{
    #Ensure we stop on errors
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
    #Connect to the SSRS webservice 
    $ssrs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "$reportServerUrl" -UseDefaultCredential;
    $namespace = $ssrs.GetType().Namespace;
    $changesMade = $false;

    #Look for a matching policy     
    $policies = $ssrs.GetPolicies($folder, [ref]$inheritFromParent);
    if ($policies.GroupUserName -contains $userGroup)
    {
        Write-Host "User/Group already exists. Using existing policy.";
        $policy = $policies | where {$_.GroupUserName -eq $userGroup} | Select -First 1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        #A policy for the User/Group needs to be created
        Write-Host "User/Group was not found. Creating new policy.";
        $policy = New-Object -TypeName ($namespace + '.Policy');
        $policy.GroupUserName = $userGroup;
        $policy.Roles = @();
        $policies += $policy;
        $changesMade = $true;
    }

    #Now we have the policy, look for a matching role
    $roles = $policy.Roles;
    if (($roles.Name -contains $requiredRole) -eq $false)
    {
        #A role for the policy needs to added
        Write-Host "Policy doesn't contain specified role. Adding.";
        $role = New-Object -TypeName ($namespace + '.Role');
        $role.Name = $requiredRole;
        $policy.Roles += $role;
        $changesMade = $true;
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Policy already contains specified role. No changes required.";
    }

    #If changes were made...
    if ($changesMade)
    {
        #...save them to SSRS
        Write-Host "Saving changes to SSRS.";
        $ssrs.SetPolicies($folder, $policies);
    }
    Write-Host "Complete.";
}

[string]$url = "http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService2006.asmx?wsdl";
Add-SSRSUserRole $url "Everyone" "Browser" "/MyReportFolder" $true;
Add-SSRSUserRole $url "Domain\User" "Browser" "/MyReportFolder" $true;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that it isn't two lines, it's great to have an answer after 7 years :)

Comment: Just to note, this script worked fine once I changed the url to `/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl`

Answer (score 0):

Yo realicé la ejecución de este shell y obviamente cambié los parametros según mi conveniencia, es decir obviamente el nombre del usuario, la localización de la carpeta y funcionó de cierta forma, digo de cierta forma porque en realidad si le otorgó el acceso solicitado al usuario, pero no solamente a la carpeta especificada, sino que a todos los reportes que se tienen las otras carpetas del power bi, esto resultó más engorroso debido a que tuve que de forma manual quitar todas las autorizaciones a ese usuario en las demás carpetas.
Pero igualmente gracias por la información.